# json rpc много параметров

Tags: python, json, json-rpc

Начал изучать json-rpc и возник вопрос, как отправлять несколько параметров?

```
{"method":"test","params":{"targethost":"host", "service":"ssh", "user":"username","version":"2.231"}}
```

В ответ получаю Invalid JSON-RPC request: params must be a list.

Answer (score 0):

В JSON-rpc параметры (params) должны быть списком, а не объектом.
Например:

```
{
    "method": "test", 
    "params": [
        "host", 
        "ssh", 
        "username", 
        "2.231"
    ]
}
```